# Property 'only' does not exist on describe

Tags: mocha.js

I'm trying to test an application with Mocha.

In Mocha I should be able to use the [`only` feature](https://mochajs.org/#exclusive-tests) to select a sublist of tests to run, like:

```js
describe.only('my tests', () => {
    // my tests...
})
```

instead of the usual:

```js
describe('my tests', () => {
    // my tests...
})
```

But `only` returns the compile-time error:

> Property 'only' does not exist on type ...

`describe` and `it` are well recognized and work fine.

Why is `only` not recognized? It is part of the official Mocha, is not an extension or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the cause, but adding this at the beginning solved the problem:

```js
import { it, describe } from 'mocha'
```

Now I'm able to compile the TypeScript code and the tests are executed fine.

Note: don't include `only` in the imports.